# Find the values of $a$ and $c$ to make $f(x)$ continuous at $x = 4$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 2cx, \quad x<4\\ x+a, \quad x=4\\ x^{2}-6, \quad x>4\end{cases}$$

I have to solve for $c$ and $a$. So far I got $5/4$ for $c$ and $4$ for $x$. Not sure how to go to $a$.

Comment: Please typeset your question properly

Comment: @DavidG.Stork yup, sorry about that

Comment: You must have found what $\lim_{x\to4^+}f(x)$ is. Solve $$f(4) = 4+a = \lim_{x\to4^+}f(x).$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Remember that a function $f: I\subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continous at $x=x_{0}$ if, and only if, $$\lim_{x\to x_{0}}f(x)=f(x_{0}).$$ Please, add your attempts for to solve the problem.

Comment: @peterwhy in that case 4 + a = 10 so a would be 6. is my c value correct?

Comment: @Alex i equated the limits, approaching from left and right so: 2cx = x^2 - 6. after subbing in the 4, that was 8c = 10, c = 5/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a function $f$ to be continuous at $x = a$, we must have the following:

1. $ \lim_{x \to a} {f(x)} $ exists
2. $f$ is defined at $x = a$
3. $ \lim_{x \to a} {f(x)} = f(a) $

Given

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
2cx, & x<4 \\
x+a, & x=4 \\
x^2-6, & x>4
\end{cases} , $$

the first part you've solved (for $c$) is correct. This comes from the limits from the left and right needing to be equal in order for the limit to exist (condition 1 above):

$$ \lim_{x \to 4^-} {f(x)} = \lim_{x \to 4^-} {f(x)} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to 4^-} {2cx} = \lim_{x \to 4^-} {x^2-6} $$
$$ \Rightarrow 8c = 10 $$
$$ \Rightarrow c = \frac{5}{4} . $$

We also need $f$ to be defined at $x = 4$, which it is: $f(4) = 4+a$. This satisfies condition 2 above.

The final condition is that the limit is equal to the function at $x = 4$:

$$ \lim_{x \to 4} {f(x)} = f(4) $$
$$ \Rightarrow 2c*4 = 4+a $$
$$ \Rightarrow 2*\frac{5}{4}*4 = 4+a $$
$$ \Rightarrow 10 = 4 + a $$
$$ \Rightarrow a = 6 . $$

So, we need $c = \frac{5}{4}$ in order for the limit to exist at $x = 4$, and we need $a = 6$ in order for the limit to equal the function at $x = 4$.